Component identification: SG50 00 X AATG
I'm looking for help identifying the IC centered in this photo.
It is labeled:
SG50
00 X
AATG

It's a 20-pin package. Based on the reset of the circuit, I suspect this is a two-channel audio codec of some kind, probably with an I2S interface. It's wired to a host microcontroller and 4x audio isolation transformers.


It's an SGTL5000XNLA3 audio codec IC from Freescale/NXP in a QFN20 package.


Image Source

Body Marking for SGTL5000XNLA3R2 on the NXP Community site gives a breakdown of the marking code: Line a (SG50): indicates the device part number; Line b (00 X): Is the mask set and revision number; Line c (AATG): Is a manufacturing trace code
